# Arduino UNO - data logging

Tags: logging, if-statement, serial-port, switch-statement, arduino

I am using an [Arduino Uno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#ArduinoUno) for some data logging. I want to oboserve it and start the log with a command from the serial command line. But I also want to be able to close the serial monitor without stopping the logger.

I expected when I write 1 in serial, the "sta" is set to the input which leads sta2 = 1, which should stay high when I'm closing the monitor, but apparently it isn't.

#### Code

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()){
        ser = Serial.read();
        switch (ser){
            case '0':
                sta = 0;
                sencortjek = 1;
                Serial.println("logger stopped");
                break;
            case '1':
                sta = 1;
                Serial.println("logger started");
                if (sta == 1){
                    sta2 = 1;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (sta2 == 1)
    {
        prog();
    }
}
```

Every time a logging is take, a LED on the board blinking. when I close the monitor, it stops.

Comment: What were you expecting that didnt happen ? I am assuming the `I dont` is a typo and not in the actual code.

Comment: sorry. yes it was a mistake. I have changed it.

Comment: I expected when i write 1 in serial the "sta" is set to the input which leads sta2 = 1, which should stay high when i'm closing the monitor, but apparently it isn't

Comment: Please edit the question the sequence that shows "doesn't work"  I think you are saying you start program, type 1, see logging start, stop the monitor in IDE, and somehow see that logging stopped?  With the serial monitor stopped, you haven't explained how you know it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The LED blinking on the arduino is rx/tx, because the serial port is in use. when you start the serial monitor, your arduino reboots. if you don't ahve anything on ther serial port reading the data stream (monitor is closed) you are not logging anything anyway.